# Indexing to a data frame for function produces partial error

Tags: r

I would like to know the reason and possible solution of the error in the below function. Indexing to a data frame produces an error while when the function is applied directly does not. It appears to me is indexing related but cannot figure out why or how to index to the data frame without producing the mentioned error.

```
z2p  <-c(23.20,20.40,20.66,20.52,20.82,21.46,21.58,22.06,22.24,23.10,23.76,24.20,25.42,28.90,31.60,31.62,27.84,29.90,29.38,30.16,30.78,33.54,37.20,44.90,45.90,46.96,52.26,46.84,40.16,39.86,42.96,45.02,47.00,43.00,47.58,47.02,49.40,46.36,44.80,42.54,40.06,37.12,37.30,37.30,36.60,32.92,28.80,36.40,38.32,37.72,35.20,36.50,38.26,41.40,42.06,43.48,47.08,45.00,46.78,43.52,45.50,45.44,46.00,45.92,46.24,46.60,47.08,46.66,50.50,49.06,48.50,47.38,48.66,49.44,44.68,45.74,48.80,49.30,49.20,48.22,48.46,44.48,41.30,42.74,46.64,47.48,48.60,48.06,50.60,49.92,51.85,56.02,56.30,59.62,62.66,62.22,62.38,59.44,59.10,57.88,57.88,57.42,56.08,55.60,58.72,59.88,60.30,57.12,55.96,56.20,55.67,55.64,55.52,54.62,56.30,59.10,58.71,58.64,57.76,60.24,59.04,61.38,60.86,60.94,64.07,63.48,70.30,71.10,73.32,73.35,70.46,72.80,72.56,72.50,72.10,72.08,77.80,79.04,88.28,93.80,94.72,91.00,93.78,89.46,89.14,89.96,80.24,76.58,78.04,87.90,76.80,69.98,64.28,59.78,51.28,56.40,61.30,59.44,57.91,63.61,65.72,66.46,65.66,67.06,65.72,76.43,80.13,81.27,77.00,70.55,79.69,78.12,78.78,82.68,79.56,79.68,80.11,81.75,87.28,83.63,83.30,79.07,77.39,74.17,73.00,71.04,77.86,78.76,76.30,78.37,78.45,81.15,80.45,79.36,83.33,84.84,84.34,88.20,86.35,88.08,89.70,96.93,102.16,104.20,106.32,114.07,111.92,115.87,111.22,113.51,115.09,116.53,118.56,111.60,115.78,124.97,128.85,128.34,126.56,125.43,137.25,137.92)

wavelet<- c("d2","s2") 

nlevel  <-  seq(1: as.integer (floor (logb ((length(z2p)),base=2)))) 

library(wmtsa)

w4      <- expand.grid ( wavelet = wavelet , nlevels = nlevel , stringsAsFactors = FALSE ) 
se    <- seq  (  nrow  (  w4  )  )
fun <- function ( i )  wavMODWT ( z2p ,  wavelet = w4[,1][i]   , n.levels = w4[,2][i]   ) 
DWT  <- lapply( se  , fun )

# the same results occur as below when using the $ sign

str(DWT[[1]])
#List of 6
$ data      : Named num [1:222] -57.36 -1.4 0.13 -0.07 0.15 ...
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:222] "d1(0)" "d1(1)" "d1(2)" "d1(3)" ...
$ scales    : Named num [1:222] 80.6 21.8 20.5 20.6 20.7 ...
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:222] "s1(0)" "s1(1)" "s1(2)" "s1(3)" ...
$ series    :Error in `[[.wavTransform`(object, i) : 
Index must be on the interval [1,2]
```

Comment: I think you'll have to look into `wmtsa` code to find out the reason. I think it is something related to `$ series`. You can also try and play around with [str arguments](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/str.html), e.g., `str(DWT[[1]], list.len=2)` will work because it doesn't reach the _faulty_ entry. For your purposes, you may also try to use other methods of the [resulting class](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/wmtsa/docs/wavTransform) instance, e.g., `summary`.

Comment: There are 6 related results of which only two are produced. My question is why this is the case. The $ series also produces the error. The resulting class is "wavtransform". where nonthing is related as per classes in your reference. In any case thank you